# Cost of JOIN with indices

Tags: sql, relational-database, b-tree, b-tree-index

Given the following:

```
blocksize = 4K
relation students(S#, Sname, Age,....)
relation taken(S#, C#, Grade)
Number of student records = 10,000
Number of taken records = 50,000
Size of student records = 200 bytes
Size of taken records = 50 bytes
```

If there's a B-Tree index on taken's S#, and "students JOIN taken" is done using that index, how much would it cost to perform the JOIN?

Assuming each B-Tree node contains up to 4K data (= blocksize).

Comment: what do you mean by 'cost' exactly?

Comment: are you asking about logical reads?

Comment: @SamD there's supposed to be some kind of formula (block transfers + seeks)